# Modificar cada elemento de un Array (object) en Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

quisiera modificar el valor de cada casilla del array mas que nada utilizando algo similar al .split. El tipo de dato que devuelve getValues() de la clase Range de Google spreadsheet es object por lo tanto no me deja usar el split. Quisiera saber si existe algo similar para manipular dicho objeto, cuando quiero utilizar el .split me indica el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: arr[x].split is not a function
```

Mi objetivo es tomar de cada celda una parte de lo anotado mediante un separador.

Solución:

```
//Recorro cada elemento del array con un bucle for.
 var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(),
 array = hoja.getRange("L:L").getValues(),
 var nuevoarray = []
for(x=0;x<array.length;++x){
 let string = array[x].join()
 string.split(';',1)
 nuevoarray.push(string); /*Va añadiendo los string recortados a un nuevo
 array sin perder el orden*/
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente `getValues()` devuelve un objeto pero este objeto es del tipo `Array` Revisa los métodos de este tipo o bien podrías usar `JSON.stringify()` para convertir tu objeto en un `String`. Si necesitas una orientación mas puntual te sugiero agregar ejemplos de datos de entrada y del resultado esperado

Comment: Añadí la solución que se me ocurrió

Answer (score 0):

No me queda claro que es lo que quieres lograr. Si quieres convertir una columna de Google Sheets en un Array (unidimensional) podrías usar `Array.prototype.flat()`

Ejemplo

```
var flattened = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheeet().getRange('L:L').getValues().flat();
```